# Spring Boot ClassNotfoundException EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9. When packaging an application as an executable war (layout is WAR) and running it, it only works with mvn spring-boot:run.
As soon as I start the application by java -jar , I get a NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURL     ClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
```

spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar is in WEB-INF/lib.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, just wondering did you get this resolved? I currently have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much for your reply. I had this plugin in my pom.xml, but the problem was that I had specified

```
<layout>WAR</layout>
```

in my pom. When I changed it to

```
<layout>ZIP</layout>
```

it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You must add redis dependence:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI Can you check your build part in your pom.xml. Am using the below mentioned and able to run in windows using: java -jar myapp.jar. **Just make sure that you are creating an executable jar.**

```
<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```